# How do i get the ios device token under air3.4

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

With the new adobe air3.4 APNs are supposed to be built in. However I cant seem to get ios to return a device token. My callbacks are not called.

All the relevant classes are imported. And the app installs and registers notifications as it is supposed to

I have the following code (and i am certain it is executed as i can trace the various objects):

```
                            var remoteNotifier:RemoteNotifier = new RemoteNotifier();

                try 
                {
                    trace("try token");
                    remoteNotifier.addEventListener(RemoteNotificationEvent.TOKEN, tokenRecieved);
                }
                catch (err:Error)
                {
                    trace("token error: " + err.message);
                }

                try 
                {
                    trace("try statusevent")
                    remoteNotifier.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, subscriptionFailureCallback);
                }
                catch (err:Error)
                {
                    trace("statusevent error: " + err.message);
                }

                trace("remote notifier: " + remoteNotifier);



                // calling subscribe method without any subscribe options automatically subscribes 
                // for all notification styles supported on that platform
                //CONFIG::DEBUGGING { traceTF("subscribe - notifications"); }
                try 
                {
                    trace("try subscribe")
                    remoteNotifier.subscribe();

                }
                catch (err:Error)
                {
                    trace("subscribe error: " + err.message);
                }
```

Neither the RemoteNotificationEvent or the StatusEvent is called. What to do?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a provisioning cert with APE's? Did you include the Entitlements block in your app.xml?

Comment: Yes and yes. And these are both set up correctly. Ive had it working with Native extension frameworks but wanted to change to the new default framework.

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing what kind of notifications you want to subscribe to.
Try adding this:

```
var preferredStyles:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
preferredStyles.push(NotificationStyle.ALERT, NotificationStyle.BADGE, NotificationStyle.SOUND);
var subscribeOptions:RemoteNotifierSubscribeOptions = new RemoteNotifierSubscribeOptions();
subscribeOptions.notificationStyles = preferredStyles;
```

And then when you subscribe you do it with the options:

```
remoteNotifier.subscribe(subscribeOptions);
```